# Password Validation Using Regular Expressions in Grails

Tags: java, regex, grails

I am using following Regular expression

```
'^(?!.*(.)\\{4})(?=.*[0-9 \\Q~!@#$%^&*()-_=+[]{}|;:,.<>/?]{2,})(?=.*[a-zA-Z]{2,}){8,50}$'
```

for the conditions:

- The password must contain at least 8 characters and no more than 50.
- The password must contain at least 2 letters.
- The password cannot contain more than 4 instances of the same character.
- The password must contain at least 5 unique characters.
- The Password must contain at least 2 unique numbers (symbols count as numbers).

When I am trying to run the application using Grails its throwing unclosed character class exception. I am also doubtful on the part where 5 unique characters condition must be checked. Help me out of  this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you write that regular expression yourself?  if your like me and usually just steal regular expressions from the web i would go back and verify with where ever you got it.

Comment: Quote the complete error message, please.

Comment: wow. remind me to never, ever, try to sign up for your website.

Comment: seriously, are you trying to make sure that no one ever uses your application?

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek - good one! Users will certainly not find it easy :-)

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek- well i know its very complex ...but have to implement that

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether grails has any special handling of this but in java, which presumbaly grails delegates to you need to escape the special characters, the unclosed character class is caused by the [] between the + and the {} almost certainly.

You'd be better off using some of the character class \p{punct} to avoid these problems.

Having said that this would be easier and clearer in code. Define various character sets and check membership as you iterate through the password. This has the added benefit that you can avoid SQL injection nasties explicitly.